# Fade animation (show / hide) in setInterval issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm using jQuery 3.2.1 and trying to create *text slider* on my landing page. I want to toggle a few  elements, so that only one is visible at a time, and after a few seconds it fades out, and next element (or the first one, if none) fades in.

**The problem is**, that after several cycles (in chrome at least), suddenly **all** of the elements fadeIn and fadeOut simultaneously, at the same time.

Here's my HTML:

```js
$('#animate-text h1').hide();
var currText = 0;
var texts = $('#animate-text h1');
var element = texts.eq(currText);
element.fadeIn(1000);

setInterval(function(){
    currText++;
    if(currText > texts.length-1) currText = 0;
    element.fadeOut(1000);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        element = texts.eq(currText);
        element.fadeIn(1000);
    },1000);
},3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='animate-text'>
    <h1> text1 </h1>
    <h1> text2 </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe try considering using the fadeOut complete callback http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Comment: Yes, this is more reasonable way than 'setTimeout' like in my code, I tried it at first, but the result was the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a "stop" function, the api says

**Description: Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.**

so this way the animations shouldnt stack up, at least in my chrome everything works fine

```js
$('#animate-text h1').hide();
var currText = 0;
var texts = $('#animate-text h1');
var element = texts.eq(currText);
element.fadeIn(1000);

setInterval(function(){
    currText++;
    if(currText > texts.length-1) currText = 0;
    element.fadeOut(1000);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        element = texts.eq(currText);
        element.stop(true,true)
        element.fadeIn(1000);
    },1000);
},3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='animate-text'>
    <h1> text1 </h1>
    <h1> text2 </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: How does this work for the same Image element by fading out previous `src` and fading in new `src`?

Comment: u could make use of the load event to fade in the img when the new src loaded